# Image tag with external (non-image) url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a Rails 4.1 app I need to insert a image with the next source url structure

```
<img src="http://example.com/link.html?param1=1234&param2=5678" />
```

Placing that in a blank html file works fine, it retrieve a image from that url and show it. But in my rails app it shows nothing.

Also, Chrome Inspector didn't see it as an image, just as "other" resource (html blank file)

What can I do to show that image from that url?

Thank you!

**Update:**
The output of that line is:

```
<img src="http://example.com/link.html?param1=1234&param2=5678" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;">
```

Almost the same for a `<%= image_tag("http...") %>` tag

```
<img alt="Link" src="http://example.com/link.html?param1=1234&param2=5678" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;" width="0" height="0">
```

Comment: Are you using an a tag to show an image? Or is that a typo, it should be an img tag.

Comment: It's a typo, sorry about that, question updated

Comment: What is your rails code for this?

Comment: It's just that code. I tried to put it with a image_tag rails code, but the result it's the same.

Comment: Did you try like this `image_tag("http://example.com/link.html?param1=1234&param2=5678")`?

Comment: Yes, and the result is the same: nothing showed and chrome didn't detect it as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad-block was blocking the banner. I hadn't even thought about that...